Exchange 2016 to office 365 migration
What would you say I'd the best method for 80 odd users the plan is to decom the on prem server post migration does that rule out remote move migration I know it used to at least I think it did.
The last few large scale migrations I have done were all remote move migrations in hybrid environments for large user base.
The last time I did one for a small company years ago I used the cutover method as it all just went over in a weekend with minimal user Impact anyway any advise would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
